# Android webview using GSAP: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread

Tags: javascript, java, android, animation, webview

In Android Studio 1.4 using the Nexus5 emulator, every time there is a 3D animation (x, y, rotationX, rotationY, rotationZ) using [GSAP](http://greensock.com/gsap) in the webview, the logcat spits out a ton of this message:

```
Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
```

This doesn't appear to affect my webapp's behavior other than a bit of stuttering when the message is produced, which is multiple times a second for animations that take a few seconds to complete.

Any ideas on how to stop, or is this even a problem?

UPDATE: The error does not occur on my test device, Samsung Galaxy S4. So it is likely only an emulator problem.

Comment: mark, unfortunately there is too little information in your message, but it looks like some bug in WebView. It may not appear on your test device because it runs a different version of WebView -- you can check the version in Settings > Apps > Android System WebView. If you create a bug report from the following link providing repro steps, the team will take a look at it: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/entry?template=Webview%20Bugs

Comment: I also have these messages in logcat and they always precede the hangup of WebView which looks like much as described in [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=539373). Most interesting thing is that I don't utilize graphics in web pages. The issue is restricted so I can't participate.

Comment: This looks to be the same issue as the one I answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46510364/2510655

Answer (score 16):

I think you are using a webview without a host GPU emulation.

Google team says in the issue:

```
"You shouldn't expect that WebView will be usable without host GPU emulation any time soon.

Note also that since the emulator doesn't receive WebView updates, testing on the emulator means you are using a much older version of WebView than the vast majority of your users, and so it's already rather unrepresentative. :/"
```

Check the issue report:

*https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=189040