# How to enable host GPU emulation with genymotion?

Tags: android-emulator, genymotion

While using AVD it's pretty easy, however I just can't figure out how could I do that with Genymotion's emulator.

And I need that, because of an requirement of the following resolution of an error that I need to fix and its solution: [StackOverFlow error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32911238/android-webview-using-gsap-attempt-to-remove-non-jni-local-reference-dumping-t)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Genymotion always uses host GPU emulation: it won't start without it.

What you may be needing is a webview with GPU acceleration support. The easiest way to get this is to:
- install the GApps through the "Open GApps" button (first icon in the right toolbar)
- open Google Play
- search for "Android System WebView" and update it